# lc3 assembly - converting ASCII to numeric

Tags: assembly, lc3

I have an ASCII character in R0 and have been given the following instructions in order to return the numeric equivalent in R0:

```
Find the index of the given ASCII_digit in “0123456789ABCDEF”
The index is the Numeric_Digit equivalent of the given ASCII_Digit
```

Seems like it would be a piece of cake but the process of checking character by character of :

```
DIGITS  .STRINGZ "0123456789ABCDEF" ;Digit_String
```

Is what entirely confuses me.

How would you accomplish that?

I suppose you would add the inverse of the string at the current index to the ASCII in R0 and if it returns 0 you found your character?

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: Loop through the string and return the index the corresponding value is found at?

Comment: @S.Klumpers yes, that is the logical thing to do. Implementing it on the LC3 is what i'm confused about. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you tired so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
LEA R1, DIGITS ;R1 is our string pointer/counter
START
    LD R2, R1 ;get the current character
    ADD R1, R1, 1 
    NOT R2, R2 ;these lines
    ADD R2, R2, 1 ;get the two's complement of R2, equivalent to -R2
    ADD R3, R0, R2 ;this is like cmp r0, r2
    BRnz ;loop back unless the characters are equal
LEA R2, DIGITS
NOT R2, R2 ;R2 = 1 - R2, we account for the 0
ADD R1, R1, R2
```

After this the integer value of the character in R0 is in R1. R0 is untouched.

I'm assuming LC3 uses two's complement representation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will definitely be trying this soon. I'm confused as to when you say LC3 is a language specifically designed for educative purposes. It is actually a machine and I'm able to program for it in both assembly and machine language. Am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: Huh, that explains why there's so little documentation, removed the last paragraph.